# Don't create apk with gradle

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I want to compile the project with gradle, but I don't want to create the apk.
How can I do this?

Thank you very much
Angelo

Answer (score 1):

Use Build option instead of Run to avoid generating apk, Using this will compile your application instead of creating an Apk file and installing on the target device.